# Lodash imports entire bundle on named imports

Tags: reactjs, lodash

Both the lines below are contributing the same size to the bundle.

```
import _ from "lodash";

import { get } from "lodash";
```

I am expecting Line-2 to be of less size. ( Refer to the image )

Named imports cost less in Ant Design which is not working in lodash.

Is there a way to reduce this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use default imports

The below line should do the job.

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
```

Yes, Ant Design named imports would give you the component you import.

This functionality is yet to be seen in lodash.